# Case in-insensitive lookup in an Excel table

Tags: excel, find, lookup, vba

I need to search a value on the first column of a Table in Excel and delete the correspondent Table row. The search must be case insensitive.

If I use .Find method on the Table.DataBodyRange a range is returned, but I do not know where this range is located relatively to the Table.DataBodyRange.

```
Set oCell = oTable.ListColumns("Client name").DataBodyRange.Find(what:=szClientName, MatchCase:=False, searchformat:=False)

oTable.ListRows(oCell.Row).Delete 'THIS DOES NOT DELETE THE TABLE ROW WHERE szClientName HAS BEEN FOUND BUT IT DELETES THE WORKSHEET ROW WHERE oCell IS LOCATED
```

If I use the Application.match method on Table.DataBodyRange, it returns the Index of found element relatively to the Table but unfortunately the search is case sensitive.

```
vIndex = Application.Match(szClientName, oTable.ListColumns("Client Name").DataBodyRange, 0)

oTable.ListRows(vIndex).Delete 'THIS DELETES THE TABLE ROW BUT THE SEARCH ON szClientName IS CASE SENSITIVE
```

How can I do what I need to do?

Comment: Application.Match is *not* case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Your first solution didn't work because oCell returns a `Range` object that is not relative to your table/list `oTable`.

Although not an elegant solution, this should work:

```
Set oCell = oTable.ListColumns("Client name").DataBodyRange.Find(what:=szClientName, MatchCase:=False, searchformat:=False)
oCell.EntireRow.Delete
```

I did not put any error checking here; if it finds nothing the code will throw an error.